# Spring Security AuthenticationSuccessHandler and MockMvc

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test-mvc

after successfully authetication i save autheticated user within a session.
After that i retrieve a user within any controller with @SessionAttributes("user")

Now i am trying to test it:

```java
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = SpringSecurityTestConfig.class
)
public class ProfileMetaDataControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private MyController myController;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).build();
    }
    @Test
    @WithUserDetails("userMail@hotmail.com")
    public void shouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
        String expectedValue ="greeting";
        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/contentUrl")
                                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                                .content("romakapt@gmx.de"))
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(content().string(expectedValue))
                    .andReturn();
     }
}
```

And my controller, which will be tested:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/profile")
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class ProfileMetaDataController {

    @GetMapping("/contentUrl")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> getInformation(Model model) throws IOException {
        User user = Optional.ofNullable((User) model.asMap().get("user")); //User ist null!!!!
    }
}
```

User is null, cause my AuthenticationSuccessHandler never invokes onAuthenticationSuccess method, where i store user within a session.

How can i deal with it? 
usually UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter invokes my AuthenticationSuccessHandler, but not during MockMVC Test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not any another reason, don't use `@SessionAttributes`.
In normally, Authentication user is stored at `SecurityContextHolder`
like this:

```java
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

If you want to get user at controller, try this 3 things.

```java
public List<String> getInformation(@AuthenticationPrincipal YourUser youruser) {
    // ...
}

public List<String> getInformation(Principal principal) {
    YourUser youruser = (YourUser) principal;
    // ...
}

public List<String> getInformation(Authentication authentication) {
    YourUser youruser = (YourUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I like solution with @AuthenticationPrincipal and i know about SecurityContextHolder. 
But i don't want to write on each controller-handler method this statement "SecurityContextHolder.getContext()..."
That was a reason to put domain-user object into a session. Cause i can access this domain-object everytime without additional code